# Rails 4: nested attributes not displaying with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested-attributes

I am trying to include nested attributes inside my Devise edit.html.erb file.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :tutor, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tutor, allow_destroy: true

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

and

```
class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
        u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email,
        :is_tutor, :password,
        # This is important for nested attributes
        tutor_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :user_id, :description] 
        :password_confirmation, :current_password)
      end
    end
end
```

And my view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

  <p>
    <%= f.check_box :is_tutor %>
    <%= f.label :is_tutor, 'Tutor' %>
  </p>

    <div>
        <%= f.fields_for :tutor do |builder| %>
        <fieldset>
            <%= builder.label :description, 'Description' %><br />
            <%= builder.text_area :description %><br />
            <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
            <%= builder.check_box :_destroy, 'Remove description' %>
        </fieldset>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <br />
  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

When I go to the edit page, I do not see the fieldset with the nested attributes. The query to the db looks like this:

> User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" A
>   SC LIMIT 1
>
> Tutor Load (3.2ms)  SELECT "tutors".* FROM "tutors" WHERE "tutors"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "tuto
>   rs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What's `resource` set to? Is it a new user?

Comment: That's Devise's default setting. It's the form for the current user session I imagine, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact there is not a tutor association connected to the user.  The fields would not show if the tutor was nil.

If so, you'll need to figure out how to do this on the user.

```
@user.build_tutor
```

Some options for adding this - You may need to overwrite the devise controller/method to add this.  There may be some hooks provided by devise.  You may do this in the view.

Comment: I've added <%= f.fields_for current_user.build_tutor do |builder| %>

This seems to display the fieldset, but when I update the form, the text is not stored and disappears every time I try updating.

By the way, current_user is provided by Devise.

Comment: In the view you can look for a tutor first, before building a new one.  (current_user.build_tutor unless current_user.tutor).  Ideally, this would be done in the controller, but you can do it anywhere before the fields are displayed in the form.

Comment: I tried that in the view but it breaks (the page doesn't even show up)

Comment: I've added `current_user.tutor.nil? ? current_user.build_tutor : current_user.tutor` to the controller and now the form seems to appear. However, I am still not able to retrieve/see the record (I'm not sure if it's saving it at all)

Comment: Edit: that line of code only works the first time round, so it's as if it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I don't think you want to do this to 'current_user' (sorry for my comment above) as that is different than the user in the form.  You'll either want to add it to resource or to f.object.  When you submit - it should naturally add the tutor object to the user and you'll have a tutor object on the user for the second time the page is displayed.

Comment: Really? What's the difference between the user in the form, current_user and resource??

Comment: The current_user will hit the devise method and get the current logged in user.  In the 'new' method, this may be coincidentally the same user, but after the post it will be a user created from the attributes of the post.  It will do a User.new(params[:user]) and not be related to current_user anymore.